# Can character devices be mapped to memory?

Tags: memory, mapping, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping, memory-mapped-io

Why we can map block device files to memory but not character files? I know block devices can be mapped to memory, but character devices can't. Why is it like that? I have no idea. Maybe someone can help me. What's difference between block device and character device? It would be nice to understand.